# How to manage tfs permissions with powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs

I need to connect to a TFS collection and change the permissions of user X, is there any way to do this through PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the tfssecurity executable to perform these actions.

Take a look at the following link and see if the functionality you desire is supported:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252504.aspx

Comment: If I could give an example I would appreciate

Comment: @user3517093 I might be able to give you an example if you can state what permissions you are looking to change for user X.